# (.py) got converted to exe but while executing fails to find ib\ext\anywrapper.py ... (IBPY)

Tags: pyinstaller, ibpy

I am using `interactive broker api` - `ibpy`. I have generated an executable using `pyinstaller` as well as `cx_freeze`.

The executable gets created in both the cases but while executing it gives the same error that it could not find the file `ib\ext\AnyWrapper.py`.

```
File "lib\site-packages\ib\opt\message.py", line 153, in <module>
File "lib\site-packages\ib\opt\message.py", line 31, in __ init__

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI27882\\ib\\ext\\AnyWrapper.py'
```

In the above example, the temp folder gets deleted, but while using `cx_freeze` it could see that the file `ib\ext\AnyWrapper.pyc` existed.

Could this be some error in `ib\opt\message.py` itself while looking for `AnyWrapper`? Should it be looking for `AnyWrapper` and not `AnyWrapper.py`?

Is it a bug with `IBPY` or is it something else?

Comment: can you show command used for packaging (ex pyinstaller file --options.....)

Comment: pyinstaller --onefile ".......path to main.py"  (please also note that I have also used cx_freeze which does not create a single executable file however the error while executing remains the same)